Microsoft asking me to remove Postgis to migrate database, any risk assoacited?
We are migrating our Postgresql Single Server to Flexible Server using Azure Migration and after a series of errors, the support engineer is telling me to remove the postgis extension for the migration to work successfully.
My wonder is - is there any risk associated with me removing the extension and re-adding it later? Data corruption?
I am aware that spatial functions and other postgis-related stuff may be unavailable during the migration period. I am mostly worried with irreversible errors that dropping the extension may cause
I'd appreciate a lot some guidance before proceeding!

Step 0: Make a backup!

after the backup create a new table remove all unnecessary columns so that primary key and spatial data remains, and export that and then try t import that alone into a table  in azure, if the data fis stored correctly make some tests to check that, the remove the spatial columns, remove the extension and migrate the data into azure and join the data to the table again

Dropping the PostGIS extension is a non-starter if you are using its data types (geometry or geography) in table definitions. You couldn't drop the extension without dropping these columns too...
If that Microsoft engineer recommends that, that is no good advertisement for that company's services.

I know. I inquired the engineer about potential risks and here's their response I want to clarify that we are not asking to remove it permanently. You can enable the extension once the migration is completed. 

Sorry, but that is bullshit. The moment you drop the extension, all your geometry and geography columns and all the data in them are lost...
